# Prove that $\limsup s_n + \liminf t_n \leq \limsup (s_n + t_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, limsup-and-liminf

> Prove that $\limsup s_n + \liminf t_n \leq \limsup (s_n + t_n)$. $s_n$ and $t_n$ are bounded.

I don't know how to start this, can anyone help and give a formal proof of this?

Comment: What is your definition of $\liminf , \limsup$? There are many equivalent definitions.

Comment: The best help, one can give you for such an homework question, would be a hint: Look up the definitions of lim inf and lim sup and put them into the situation. Then the problem will basically solve itself.

Comment: The first thing that you should do is correct the statement of the theorem, because what you have here is false. Suppose that $s_n=(-1)^n$ and $t_n=(-1)^{n+1}$. Then $\limsup_ns_n=1=\limsup_nt_n$, but $s_n+t_n=0$ for all $n$, so $\limsup_n(s_n+t_n)=0$, and $1+1\not\le 0$.